# SyntaxError ---- (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, unicode-escapes

Something went wrong with my code:

ERROR:
input_file = "C:\Users\khanh\OneDrive[03] Coding Project\4_HSG\04_HSGTPHCM23\TBC\TBC.IN
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

CODE:
`with open(input_file, "r") as infile: lines = infile.readlines() ds_a = list(map(int, lines[1].strip().split())) length = len(ds_a)`

I didn't try anything

Comment: `\U` is a special character in Python strings.  Put a `r` in front of the string to tell python to treat it as a "raw string" without any special handling.  `input_file = r"C:\Users\...`

Comment: Or, if you prefer, you can use forward slashes instead of backslashes.  Those do not have any special handling.  And yes they do work even on Windows.

Comment: thank you, i have put the r before it and it worked